# DateTimeZone::__construct(): Unknown or bad timezone (LHDT)

Tags: php

> new DateTimeZone("LHDT")

is giving error `DateTimeZone::__construct(): Unknown or bad timezone (LHDT)` on production server. Locally works fine.

PHP version on prod is PHP Version 7.0.30

Comment: Try `new DateTimeZone("Australia/Lord_Howe")`

Comment: @ceejayoz I want to use abbreviation -> LHDT. works fine locally only issue is with the server

Comment: As far as I can tell, `LHDT` is not an official timezone in the PHP list. Can you explain why you *must* use the abbreviation?

Answer (score 2):

The legal argument of `DateTimeZone::__construct()` should be one of the supported timezones.

Please checkout the documentation to find out a suitable timezone string for your location:

[DateTimeZone::__construct()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.construct.php)

[List of Supported Timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

**UPDATE:**

Based on @ceejayoz 's comment, in this case timezone argument would be `'Australia/Lord_Howe'`, hope this make my answer more clear.

Comment: (Which, in this case, would appear to be `Australia/Lord_Howe`).

Comment: Oh, got it , I'll update this in my answer. Thank you! @ceejayoz

Comment: I want to use abbreviation -> LHDT. works fine locally only issue is with the server

Comment: Then can you tell us what "LHDT" abbreviate for, I just found an abbreviation named "LHST" @CNV

Comment: LHDT appears to stand for "Lord Howe Daylight Savings Time". LHSD would be Lord Howe Standard Time. Neither abbreviation is supported by PHP, and both are covered properly by the `Australia/Lord_Howe` timezone setting.

Answer (score 0):

i was facing this error in laravel "Exception: DateTimeZone::__construct(): Unknown or bad timezone ()", How i solved this problem in this code.

```
            $time = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone($timezone));
            $timezoneOffset = $time->format('P');
            $temp['offset']  =  $timezoneOffset;
```

$timezone variable was empty. It should not empty and a valid timezone. Error will be removed.